# What is the “public community” in the profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page

On the bottom of [edit profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) the two buttons exist:

> [image: save]

The last one contains a term “public community”. What does it mean here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Public vs Teams.

Public communities are the 170+ sites of the Stack Exchange Network. They are accessible to everyone.

Private communities means [Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364145/coming-soon-stack-overflow-for-teams). The existence of and membership in a Team is private and only people who are members have access to the Team.

The idea is that you have a separate profile page for any Teams you're on and so the button is stating that, if you're on any Teams, a change to your *public* profile will not affect the content of those private profile pages, only the profile pages of the live, public sites on the Network.